# Swift software iOS code decision

Tags: ios, swift

I need help to decide which way to go to reduce code pain.
Upon downloading a certain form from the web in html/text format, I will decide which parts of the form to display on the iPhone for the user to see and/or interact with.

There may be Labels, TextFields, CheckBoxs, RadioButtons and Pickers to name a few. Some pages can be “transformed” into one iPhone scene but others may need scrolling (run time decision).

Since a group of those pages relate to one kind of activity, I like to use one scene/storyboard and to make views/containers show up and/or disappear as needed for the current page.

My options:

1. TableViews with either Static Cell or Prototype cell (model to supply the correct view/container).
2. StackViews for ease of laying out.
3. Hybrid of both above, stackView inside each cell for easy layout and row/cellView deleting.
4. Plain vanilla views with in a container inside a scrollView (feeling some pain about this one)
5. Collection view (maybe an overkill).

What would you do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your deployment target is `iOS 9.0` then i would suggest to go for option 3. If deployement target is below 9.0 then `stackViews` is not an option for you so in that case go for option 1. That will give you  scalability like if your fields get increased after sometimes so that change would be accommodate  easily with `TableViews` and in this case approach 4 will definitely be painful.